# unable to Access pod from another pod in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I have one app deployed in pod A and another app in pod B

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: product
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: product-api

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webbff
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: webbff-api
```

In webbff service i have written the url http://product to access the product service. But i am unable to access it

Comment: What is `containerPort` for `product`? Does `product` handle empty relative path? What's the error message?

Comment: Did you try to use the FQDN instead of just the hostname? `product.<NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: How did You try to access service? Did You get any HTTP error or response?

Comment: Do you create them in the same namespace? And do you create some network policy to block the requests? Please provide more details, and can you provide the whole YAML?

Comment: @CharlesXu: Yes i did create it in default namespace.Please find the yamls below:`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-products
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: product-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product
        image: registryakspoc.azurecr.io/product.api:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80      
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-auth`

Comment: Do you check if the pods in the running state and can you provide logs?